# Accordingly to the classical theory, if the electrons' energies depend on the intensity, then on what does the electrons' number depend?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, photoelectric-effect

In the photoelectric effect, accordingly to the classical theory, if the electrons' energies depend on the intensity of the incident light, then on what does the electrons' number depend? I mean, how can one increase the number of emitted electrons according to the classical theory?

Comment: What classical theory?

Comment: That light is electromagnetic waves

Comment: That's not a theory of the photoelectric effect.

Comment: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mod2.html